# Implement a modified Stack

Tags: c#, .net

Implement a modified stack that stores two color values ​​(red and black) and supports the following operations:

1. void Push(value, color) - push the value (value) of the color (color) to the top of the stack.
2. value Pop() - remove the top element from the top of the stack and return its value (if the stack is empty, return null).
3. value FindLastByColor(color) - find the topmost value of the color (color) on the stack without removing this element from the stack (if there are no elements of this color on the stack, return null).

Comment: Can you better explain the difference between the `value` and `color` arguments for `Push()`?

Comment: Can the stack only hold one type of value or can it be hold multiple different types like double, string, int etc. ?

Comment: You will find that debugging this will be easier if you have a type that has more than two possible values (read and black).  If you `Push(red)`, `Push(red)`, `Push(black)`, and then `Push(red)` and then you look at the top of the stack and see red, which red is it?

Comment: @rinyasuper: Write a basic stack type first. Then -- wait for it -- *modify it* to meet these requirements, and now you have a "modified stack". This question is not focused enough.

Comment: What is a "modified stack" compared to just a "stack"?

Comment: Do you want to write it from scratch (by the way, you get to write your code, we are not a code writing service).  By scratch, I mean using something like an array to hold the values (and allowing the array to expand if needed).  Can the stack overflow?  What happens if you Pop an empty stack?  I suggest, by the way, that you make this stack type generic (so that you can work with more than just your red/black type)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the stack can hold values ​​of different types, there will be no need to write a generic stack class (MyStack). Based on this assumption, the stack class that meets its needs can be designed as follows.

This is definition of my helper objects

```
public enum MyColor
{
    Red,
    Black
}

public class Item
{
    public MyColor Color { get; }
    public object Obj { get; }

    public Item(MyColor color, object obj)
    {
        Color = color;
        Obj = obj;
    }
}
```

And this is CustomStack class

```
public class MyStack
{
    private readonly Stack<Item> _items;

    public MyStack()
    {
        _items = new Stack<Item>();
    }

    public void Push(MyColor color, object value)
    {
        _items.Push(new Item(color, value));
    }

    public object? Pop()
    {
        return _items.TryPop(out Item? item) ? item.Obj : null;
    }

    public object? FindLastByColor(MyColor myColor)
    {
        var item = _items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Color == myColor);
        return item?.Obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like a quite straightforward implementation, but I would replace `Pop` with `stack.TryPop(out var item) ? item : null;`

Comment: Looks good, you could make it generic though instead of using object.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I changed the code according to your comment ;) It was a good suggestion.

Comment: `_items.TryPop(out Item? item); return item?.Obj;` - I wouldn't accept this code in a code review. That's awful throwing away the `bool` and then "recreating" it using the Elvis operator. I'd seriously go with `public object? Pop() => _items.TryPop(out Item? item) ? item : null;`

Comment: @Enigmativity Under general conditions, the effect on performance will not be felt, but since there is some truth in your comment, I will edit accordingly :)

Comment: @AdemCatamak - My concern wasn't performance. It was because it was written in a convoluted way.

Comment: @Enigmativity those are really questionable recommendations to pass code as written by "new to programming" :) Everything should be converted to string at least once to make it real...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - What?

Comment: @Enigmativity was not serious comment (tried to add smiley)... OP is looking for HW to be done and your comments made code better and more readable, but such code is not really expected from someone "new to programming". Code that makes all checks after converting everything to strings (`if (isTrue.ToString() == "true")...`) definitely have better chance to pass as one's own solution.